# How to use delegate to add a new object to Array and show it in TableView

Tags: uitableview, delegates

I'm doing a exercise that making 1 BookStore.
My book store will show all the book object in bookstore array.
My project can be understand like this:
MasterView: will show all title of the book.
DetailView: will show detail of the book whenever users tab on title book at MasterView.

My problem: I want to add one more book at the MasterView by tapping on Add button.
After adding, it should back to MasterView and show all title of book in store again (including the new book that I have added).

I know I need to create a new subview where users can input new book and need to use delegate to do it. But I'm is new in coding and Xcode, I've read some using delegate example but still cannot apply to UITableView.

Here is my project, I hope you guys can help me to understand and accomplish this.
http://wikisend.com/download/720454/SuperBookStore2.zip

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step1:** Make a new file named `"LKAddViewController"`

**Step2:** In `LKAddViewController.h` define the `UITextField` and `UIButton` and the `delegate` method for that like..

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "LKBook.h"
@protocol LKAddViewControllerDelegate;
@interface LKAddViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic,strong)IBOutlet UITextField *txtField;
@property (nonatomic) id <LKAddViewControllerDelegate> AddBookDelegate;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *author;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *titletxt;
@property (nonatomic,strong)IBOutlet UIButton *submit;
-(IBAction)btnSubmit:(id)sender;
@end



@protocol LKAddViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)AddBook:(LKBook *)newObj;

@end
```

**Step3:** In `LKAddViewController.m` write the code for submit button and call the delegate method like..

```
@implementation LKAddViewController
@synthesize AddBookDelegate;
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
-(IBAction)btnSubmit:(id)sender{
    LKBook *newBook = [[LKBook alloc] init];
    newBook.author = self.author.text;
    newBook.title = self.titletxt.text;
    newBook.desc = self.titletxt.text;
    if ([self.AddBookDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(AddBook:)]) {
        [self.AddBookDelegate AddBook:newBook];
    }
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
@end
```

**Step:4**  In `LKMasterViewController.h` import the header file and define the delegate methods like..

```
#import "LKAddViewController.h"
@interface LKMasterViewController () <LKAddViewControllerDelegate>{
```

**Step5:** Replace your `insertNewObject` method by the below code

```
- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender
{
    LKAddViewController *obj = [[LKAddViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"LKAddViewController" bundle:nil];
    obj.AddBookDelegate=self;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
//    if (!_objects) {
//        _objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
//    }
//    [_objects insertObject:[NSDate date] atIndex:0];
//    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
//    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

}
```

**step6:** Write the below method to add the new object and reload the table.

```
- (void)AddBook:(LKBook *)newObj{
    [myBookStore.BookStore addObject:newObj];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Hope this works for you and fulfill your requirements.

Comment: Im so glad to get ur answer. I will try when I at home, it seems that all I need. Many thanks to you.

Comment: Welcome. I do the same in your sample application and its working. Hope it will work for you also.

Comment: Awesome, I can do it now, actually I need to define delegate in LKMasterViewController.m not h ^^. But now I can do it, I think I should practice more to understand deeply about delegate. Thank you so much. I will vote for you when I can, so sorry because now I cannot do it since my account is still new.